# Problema conexión base de datos mysql desde NodeJS

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos `MySQL` en una máquina virtual, estoy intentando acceder a ella desde `NodeJS`, las claves están bien, pues puedo acceder remotamente (`ssh` o `MySQL Workbench`) a ella.

Este es mi código:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql')

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '10.101.136.76',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'toor',
  database: 'client_group'
})

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
})
```

Y la aplicación, devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error: connect ECONNREF
>       at Object.exports._
>       at exports._excepti
>       at TCPConnectWrap.a
>       -------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueu Protocol.js:141:48)
>       at Protocol.handsha \Protocol.js:52:41)
>       at Connection.conne on.js:136:18)
>       at Object.

¿Alguna configuración dentro del servidor `MySQL`?

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta que tal vez pueda servirte. Por favor, considera la posibilidad de eliminar las etiquetas `javascript`, `node`y `express` porque tal vez no estén relacionadas con tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La conexión ssh no es remota, más bien entras a la máquina virtual y te conectas localmente. Esto también es posible en MySQL Workbench, así que si usas ssh tal vez tu servidor no acepta conexiones remotas. Como hay varias capas de permisos (base de datos, mysql, firewall y host) tienes que asegurarte que tienes permisos en cada tramo.

- **host** - probablemente no tengas aquí problemas, pero verifica que tu firewall acepte conexiones salientes al puerto de MySQL, generalmente el `3306` o el que corresponda.
- **guest** - Tu sistema *guest* tal vez tenga un firewall, verifica que te permita conectarse hacía y desde el puerto de tu gestor de base de datos.
- **mysql** - debes permitir que MySQL *escuche* su puerto en una dirección IP específica, o bien, si esa dirección no es la que necesitas (como la *loopback*) puedes desenlazarla. Edita tu archivo `my.cnf`

  ```
  #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
  #skip-networking
  ```

  Y reinicia el servidor(**no indicas el sistema operativo guest por lo que no puedo ser más preciso**).
- **base de datos** - tu usuario debe tener permisos para acceder a la tabla desde una IP específica o desde cualquiera. Asigna a tu usuario los permisos correspondientes.

  ```
  mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'toor' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  ```

  A continuación, reinicia los privilegios.

  ```
  mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

Comment: Hola toledao, muchas gracias por contestar, acabo de revisar lo que me comentabas. He modificado el fichero my.cnf y asignado permisos(esto ya lo había hecho antes). Pero sigue fallando, dos detalles, importantes. Versión mysql server 5.7.15. Sistema de la máquina virtual, Ubuntu 14

Comment: Si tienes acceso a un cliente `mysql` podrías verificar la conexión. Si no es así, verifica nuevamente como te conectas con el Workbench y verifica que la conexión sea directa y no usando con `ssh`.

Comment: Acabo de solventarlo, cambiando #bind-address           = 127.0.0.1 por #bind-address           = 0.0.0.0

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!